# How can I get a software to write mathematical text into word?

Tags: image-processing, ms-word

I'm a third-year student who is currently deciding on my project for this year.

My project idea is a program that takes an input in the form of a photo/screenshot, detects mathematical symbols/equations, and is able to accurately output those formulas/equations in word.

For instance, usually, when copying/pasting mathematical text such as x^2 + y^2 = z^2 the result is x2 + y2 = z2, but it is possible to correctly write a superscript 2 in word. Having the program detect what has been written and compare it to a table of correct outputs doesn't seem too challenging, but allowing the program to open word and *write greek letters and equations* is something I'm struggling to understand.

I have a medium knowledge in Java, C++, Python, and some basic knowledge in SQL and C for reference.

(P.s. the included images are the sort of basic mathematical equations I'd want to be able to write)[image]
[image]

Comment: if the input is clean, you can start by doing OCR and getting each glyph and its bounding box. glyphs aren't just connected components; consider `i`, that's two connected components. -- you'd have to analyze the *arrangement* of symbols and build a tree structure from that. that's not trivial. you can implement that by hand for specific arrangements of symbols (superscript, subscript, fractions, sums, ...). if you have to ask how to *approach* this, this project is too challenging for you.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps a possibility would be to use `OpenCV` with Python for the image detection and pass the characters through a Deep Columnar Convolutional Neural Network (DCCNN), much like in this article [Computer Vision — Auto grading Handwritten Mathematical Answersheets](https://towardsdatascience.com/computer-vision-auto-grading-handwritten-mathematical-answersheets-8974744f72dd).

After this, you could try to convert the output to LaTeX format. This way, not only your code is more versatile to be used with LaTeX editors, but it is also capable of working with Microsoft and Apple tools such as Word, PPT, Pages, Keynote, etc. The bonus is that LaTeX code is, for single equations, a single line of code, so you don't need to hassle with Word for making exponents or fractions, to name a few.